# How to exclude a column from typeorm entity and could be optional to get the column using Find method

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
name: string;

@Column()
password: string;
}
```

i dont want password here because i want to return to client:

```
const user = await User.find({where:{name:"test"}})
```

when i want to modify password i need password:

```
const user = await User.findOne({where:{name:"test"}})
user.password="password";
await user.save()
```

is there any solution with Find,FindAndCount or even FindOne methods?

**How should i do?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a select option in your `@Column` decorator inside the entity like this:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({select: false})
  password: string;
}
```

This way you will not get the password field from the model if you do `find`. You'll have to explicitly do `addSelect` using `QueryBuilder`.

Reference: https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns

Comment: thanks for your answer. is it possible to pass args of Find Method to   `createQueryBuilder().where(args)` ?
because i wrote some functionality for sorting and filtering dynamicly  Find Method's Options. @rahul-sharma

Comment: `find` and `QueryBuillder`'s `where` accept arguments in different manners. Passing the json you wrote for `find` in `createQueryBuilder().where` won't be possible, I guess. You can always write any query that you wrote using `find` with `QueryBuilder`. You'll have to specify the filters in `where` and sort using `sort` method.

Comment: yes completely correct ,i finally remove the password field from returned array in Find() by using RXJS's map operator
technically after get all the fields from database

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to apply `select: false` to column in entity, then other option is to selectively type columns in find method only which you need

```
this.ManagementUnitRepository.find({
  select: ["id", "name"]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Awais Nasir